# Second conditional?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

A: If the sentence didn’t include the word “please”, the sentence would suggest I am a rude person. (The context is that the sentence includes the word “please” so the sentence doesn’t suggest I am a rude person.)

Is “would” second conditional in sentence A? I am trying to make a second conditional sentence with the context in parentheses above. I don’t even know if sentence A is in a second conditional sentence structure. Please help me.

Comment: I don’t know why not a single person is willing to help me with my questions. I am very disappointed.